# How to print pdf page with css property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, dom

```
function printDiv() {
   var divContents = document.getElementById("box2text").innerHTML;
   var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
   a.document.write('<html>');
   a.document.write('<body > <h1>Div contents are <br>');
   a.document.write(divContents);
   a.document.write('</body></html>');
   a.document.close();
   a.print();
}
```

This is html code which i am using

```
 <div class="box2" id="box2">
    <textarea name="box2text" id="box2text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="button">
    <button onclick="printDiv()">PRINT</button>
 </div>
```

This print only text I want text with its css property like color

Comment: Consider editing the question instead of dumping code into a comment

Comment: Now i changed sir.

Comment: You need some print-media css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a blank html page (print-page.html) which has your `css` linked to it. and use the following code to open it and insert your content inside and then print the content:

```js
function printDiv() {
    var divContents = document.getElementById("box2text").innerHTML;
    const printWindow = window.open('print-page.html', '_blank', `width=${window.innerWidth},height=${window.innerHeight}`);
    printWindow.onload = function(){
        printWindow.document.body.innerHTML = divContents;
        printWindow.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to use ruled paper instead of blank paper for print pdf using javascript, What will be the procedure?

Comment: @YUVRAJJWALA I don't think there's a straightforward method. But again you can use CSS to style your content as a ruled paper and then print that. This is a codepen article I found for you:  https://codepen.io/ceg9498/post/creating-lined-paper